# How are deleted files merged?

Tags: git, merge

Let's say we have 2 branches: Branch A and branch B, which are basically the same branches at the beginning, both were originated from master branch. Suppose i deleted image_1.png, image_2.png and image_3.png from branch A. I wonder what the difference is between following merges:

Case 1: I switch to branch A and merge using:

```
git merge BRANCH_B
```

Case 2: I switch to branch B and merge using:

```
git merge BRANCH_A
```

What i wonder is the following: Do deleted files are deleted after merge in both cases? Or deleted files are recovered in case 1 since I merge branch B into branch A.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you would have to solve a merge-conflict. Due to the fact you already mentioned. Files in B are still present and in A not.
In the second case the files would be deleted if I am correct.